# How can I loop through the keys of an object and set values equal to a destructured variable?

Tags: javascript, express

I am trying to simplify and shorten my current code. My code is working fine. This is what I have:

```
app.patch('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(req.body)
    const {
        leaser, propertyType, pricePerDay,
        currency, city, street, description
    } = req.body;
    const foundListing = listings.find(l => l.id === id);
    
    foundListing.leaser = leaser;
    foundListing.pricePerDay = pricePerDay;
    foundListing.propertyType = propertyType;
    foundListing.currency = currency;
    foundListing.city = city;
    foundListing.street = street;
    foundListing.description = description;

    res.redirect('/listings');
})
```

How can I make the repetitive last half of the code shorter? There is probably a way in which I can write only one line

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#syntax).

```
app.patch('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    console.log(req.body)
    const {
        leaser, propertyType, pricePerDay,
        currency, city, street, description
    } = req.body;
    
    const foundListing = {
        ...listings.find(l => l.id === id),
        ...req.body
    };

    res.redirect('/listings');
})
```

Comment: This cuts down on the lines quite significantly, but I Think there may be a couple of issues. This would put all keys of `req.body` onto found listing. It also sets the variables (`leaser`, `propertyType` etc.) which are not used. Wish I could find a good solution that cuts down the lines without these things 

Comment: I dont quite understand... The code you provided does not update the foundListing members

Comment: This is true @bjosk; `foundListing` is coped locally

Answer (score 0):

This isn't much shorter, but that's partly because we have it all in one place. If you had a util function to copy these properties, you cna just call it when needed.

Partially applying the functions is entirely down to personal preference ‍♂️

```js
const listings = [
  { id: 1, name: "a" },
  { id: 2, name: "b" },
];

const copyProperties = ps => from => to => {
  ps.forEach(p => {
    to[p] = from[p];
  });
}

const applyRequestToListing = req => copyProperties([
    "leaser",
    "pricePerDay",
    "propertyType",
    "currency",
    "city",
    "street",
    "description",
])(req);

const handleRequest = (req) => {
    const foundListing = listings.find(l => {
      return l.id === req.params.id
    });
    
    applyRequestToListing(req.body)(foundListing);
};

handleRequest({
  params: {
    id: 2,
  },
  body: {
    leaser: "leaserIn",
    pricePerDay: "pricePerDayIn",
    propertyType: "propertyTypeIn",
    currency: "currencyIn",
    city: "cityIn",
    street: "streetIn",
    description: "descriptionIn",
  },
});

console.log(listings);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.assign()` in combination with the spread operator to copy the properties of `req.body` to the `foundListing` like this:

```
const foundListing = listings.find(l => l.id === id);
Object.assign(foundListing, ...req.body)
```

Or even shorter (as you probably don't need the foundListing variable later):

```
Object.assign(listings.find(l => l.id === id), ...req.body);
```

Suddenly your code becomes really short:

```
app.patch('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
    Object.assign(listings.find(l => l.id === req.params.id), ...req.body);
    res.redirect('/listings');
})
```

If you want to copy only certain properties of `req.body`, you could do it like this:

```
const foundListing = listings.find(l => l.id === id);
["leaser", "pricePerDay", "propertyType", "currency", "city", "street", "description"].forEach((e) => {
  foundListing[e] = req.body[e];
});
```

Comment: I do not want to add additional properties. I would like to update all properties of foundListing expect for the id property. The code might work though. On my phone rn, I’ll try later!

Answer (score 0):

If all the `foundListing` properties are going to be modified, then you could loop through the properties to make changes, like so:

```
app.patch('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
    
    const { id } = req.params,
          foundListing = listings.find(l => l.id === id);

    for(const key in foundListing){ 
        foundListing[key] = req.body[key] 
    }

    res.redirect('/listings');
})
```

If you need to specify which properties are going to be modified then you can list them in an array and loop through them to make changes, like so:

```
app.patch('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
    
    const { id } = req.params,
          foundListing = listings.find(l => l.id === id),
          keys = [
             'leaser', 
              'propertyType', 
              'pricePerDay',
              'currency', 
              'city', 
              'street', 
              'description'
          ];

    keys.forEach(key => { foundListing[key] = req.body[key] })
    res.redirect('/listings');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use the following approach.

```
app.patch('/listings/:id', (req, res) => {
   const { id } = req.params;
   const foundListing = listings.find(l => l.id === id);

   Object.keys(foundListing).forEach(key => {
     foundListing[key] = req.body[key]
   })

   res.redirect('/listings');
})
```